# mostrar Arraylist en jsf

Tags: jsf

hola buenas a todos estoy iniciando en JSF y he topado con un problema que me esta volviendo loco.

Tengo una clase info_persona.
Otra clase  PersonaBean.
Una pagina xhtml MostrarTablaPersonas.xhtml.

La intención final es que conecta a una base de datos y lea todo los registros de la base de datos  lo meta en un ArrayList  después mostrar esta arrayList en la pagina xhtml.

Pero he querido empezar con algo mas sencillo .
para ver si el mecanismo funciona.
aqui el codigo que tengo

```
public class Info_Persona {
    private int num1;
    private int num2;
    private int num3;


    public Info_Persona(int num1, int num2, int num3) {
        this.num1 = num1;
        this.num2 = num2;
        this.num3 = num3;       
    }

    public int getNum1() {
        return num1;
    }


    public void setNum1(int num1) {
        this.num1 = num1;
    }


    public int getNum2() {
        return num2;
    }


    public void setNum2(int num2) {
        this.num2 = num2;
    }


    public int getNum3() {
        return num3;
    }


    public void setNum3(int num3) {
        this.num3 = num3;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Info_Persona [num1=" + num1 + ", num2=" + num2 + ", num3=" + num3 + "]";
    }
}
```

**Para la clase ManagedBean en faces-config.xml**

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>PersonaBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>paq_Persona.PersonaBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

**PersonaBean.java**

```
public class PersonaBean {
static List<Info_Persona> listaPersona = new ArrayList<>();

public void listarPers() {

    int num1 = 0;
    int num2 = 1;
    int num3 = 2;

    while (num1 < 3) {
        Info_Persona per = new Info_Persona(num1, num2, num3);
        listaPersona.add(per);
        num1++;
        num2++;
        num3++;

    }

}
```

}

**La pagina xhtml:  MostrarTablaPersona.xhtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<h1>JSF 2.0 + JDBC Example</h1>

<h:dataTable  value="#{personaBean.listaPersona()}" var="tempPers"
    styleClass="order-table" headerClass="order-table-header"
    rowClasses="order-table-odd-row,order-table-even-row">

    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
                num1
            </f:facet>
                #{tempPers.num1}
        </h:column>

    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
                num2
            </f:facet>
                #{tempPers.num2}
        </h:column>

    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
                num3
            </f:facet>
                #{tempPers.num3}
        </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 1):

En la property **value** del componente **h:datatable** deberías pasarle una colección, algo que se pueda iterar. Tu método en el controller no devuelve nada (es void). Que tu hagas un while o un for en el controller no significa que eso vaya a iterarse en la vista. No funciona así JSF. Las variables locales que tenes en tu método (**num1, num2, num3**) no son conocidas por la vista, son locales al método, luego de ejecutarse se pierden, como cualquier variable local.

JSF es un framework basado en componentes, server-side, que implementa un patrón llamado MVC, Model-View-Controller.

- **View**: se representan por las páginas .xhtml
- **Controllers**: los managed bean, donde reside la lógica de presentación
- **Model**: toda información que la vista va a mostrar, como por ejemplo una Persona.

Como estas empezando, vamos a hacer un ejemplo simple que en tu caso debería funcionar (luego puedes adaptarlo para que funcione con tus clases)

*Persona.java*

```
    public class Persona {

        private String nombre;
        private String apellido;

        public Persona(String nombre, String apellido) {

            this.persona = persona;
            this.apellido = apellido;
        }

        public void setNombre(String nombre) {

            this.nombre = nombre;
        }

        public String getNombre() {

            return nombre;
        }

        public void setApellido(String apellido) {

            this.apellido = apellido;
        }

        public String getApellido() {

            return apellido;
        }   
    }
```

Este va a ser mi Model. Tiene los respectivos **getters** y **setters** para que luego desde la vista pueda hacer referencia a estos atributos. Mas adelante te muestro como.

*Ahora agrego un método a tu managed bean para devolver una lista de personas*

```
    public List<Persona> getPersonas() {

        /* Esta inicialización es a modo de ejemplo. Los datos probablemente 
        los obtengas de una base de datos o un web service, pero a modo de 
        ejemplo sirve */
        List<Personas> personas = new LinkedList<Persona>();

        personas.add(new Persona("Diego", "Maradona"));
        personas.add(new Persona("Leonel", "Messi"));
        personas.add(new Persona("Crsitiano", "Ronaldo"));

        return personas;
    }
```

Notá que este método se llama **getPersonas** . Ahora, para poder acceder desde la vista a la lista voy a hacer algo así: **#{personaBean.personas}** . Por convención, JSF invocará el método getPersonas(). Usar setters y getters es muy común en muchos frameworks, no solo JSF. MyBatis, Hibernate, Spring, Spring-mvc por nombrar algunos.

*Por último, haré una modificación en como dibujas el datatable:*

```
    <h:dataTable  value="#{personaBean.personas}" var="persona"
        styleClass="order-table" headerClass="order-table-header"
        rowClasses="order-table-odd-row,order-table-even-row">

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Nombre</f:facet>
            #{persona.nombre}
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
           <f:facet name="header">Apellido</f:facet>
           #{persona.apellido}
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
```

Fijate como en **var** declaro la variable persona (pude haber puesto p o culaquier otro nombre). ¿De que tipo será persona? Bueno será del tipo que contenga la collección. Estos tipos de framework usan mucho la API Reflection. Mira como accedo a las properties de la clase Persona a través de sus getters:
**#{persona.nombre} y #{persona.apellido}**

Bien espero que sea útil y cualquier duda preguntas!